# Weird ggplot2 error: Empty raster

Tags: r, ggplot2

Why does

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(1,2),z=c(1.5,1.5)),aes(x=x,y=y,color=z)) +
geom_point()
```

give me the error

> Error in grid.Call.graphics(L_raster, x$raster, x$x, x$y, x$width, x$height,  : Empty raster

but the following two plots work

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(1,2),z=c(2.5,2.5)),aes(x=x,y=y,color=z)) +
geom_point()
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(1,2),z=c(1.5,2.5)),aes(x=x,y=y,color=z)) +
geom_point()
```

I'm using ggplot2 0.9.3.1

Comment: Try this and see if the error is fixed: `ggplot(data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(1,2),z=c(1.5,1.5)),aes(x=x,y=y,color=factor(z)))+geom_point()`

Comment: @N8TRO Unfortunately, I can't go that route because my data will not always have a single unique z value and I need that variable to be mapped to a continuous color scale.

Comment: So the problem is with the colour scale when you have a single value in your colour aesthetic? This all works for me on ggplot2:0.9.3.1 - what's your version of grid? I'm on 3.0.2 (from R 3.0.2).

Comment: @Spacedman The error only occurs when my z values are 1.5.  It works if my z values are not 1.5.  I'm on grid 3.0.3

Comment: +1 that is **WIERD**! Even `z=c(1.50001,1.5001)` will work. It's something strange about `1.5` for both values and how the colour scale is worked out. Good find.

Comment: Wow, that is a edge/corner/hyper-corner(?) case. Definitely file that as a bug. Note that I can also get the error for `z=c(-1.5,-1.5)`.

Comment: It's a bit weirder `ggplot(data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(1,2),z=c(1.51,1.51)),aes(x=x,y=y)) +
  geom_point(aes(color=z))` gives the same error but doesn't when the `aes` is in the main `ggplot` call, at least on R3.1 OSX10.9.2

Comment: Filed a report here https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/issues/943

Comment: FYI this works fine for me on ggplot2_0.9.1

Comment: I've found the same error with ggplot2_1.0.0.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> **TL;DR**: Check your data -- do you really want to use a continuous color scale with only one possible value for the color?

The error does not occur if you add `+ scale_fill_continuous(guide=FALSE)` to the plot. (This turns off the legend.)

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(1,2), y=c(1,2), z=c(1.5,1.5)), aes(x=x,y=y,color=z)) +
  geom_point() + scale_color_continuous(guide = FALSE)
```

The error seems to be triggered in cases where a continuous color scale uses only one color. The current GitHub version already includes the relevant [pull request](https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/pull/1077). Install it via:

```
devtools::install_github("hadley/ggplot2")
```

But more probably there is an issue with the data: why would you use a continuous color scale with only one value?

Comment: In my case, I'm creating standardized plots for 200 countries in a loop. Most countries are well-behaved and therefore the continuous scale, but one of them happens to only have one value for all variables, which throws this bug. The pull request worked like a charm.

Comment: @AmitKohli: Your case makes sense. Glad the PR works for you.

Comment: Just a note that the github fork is no longer available. (deleted by the author, it seems). It worked for me in a similar application to the OP (except that I have about 5000 plots to generate) but, after a recent upgrade to R, the patch is gone and it's now back to being broken. *sigh*

Comment: @user3396385: https://github.com/hadley/ggplot2/pull/1077 says it's been merged to `master`, but perhaps not yet released to CRAN. Try `devtools::install_github("hadley/ggplot2")`. Please let me know if it works so I can edit the answer.

Comment: @krlmlr: Thanks for the suggestion! Installing ggplot2 from github fixed the issue. Cheers!

Answer (score 4):

The same behaviour (i.e. the "Empty raster"error) appeared to me with another value apart from 1.5.

Try the following:

```
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(1,2),z=c(0.02,0.02)),aes(x=x,y=y,color=z))
+ geom_point()
```

And you get again the same error (tried with both 0.9.3.1 and 1.0.0.0 versions) so it looks like a nasty and weird bug.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely sounds like an edge case better suited for a bug report as others have mentioned but here's some generalizable code that might be useful to somebody as a clunky workaround or for handling labels/colors. It's plotting a rescaled variable and using the real values as labels.

```
require(scales)
z <- c(1.5,1.5)
# rescale z to 0:1
z_rescaled <- rescale(z)
# customizable number of breaks in the legend
max_breaks_cnt <- 5
# break z and z_rescaled by quantiles determined by number of maximum breaks 
#  and use 'unique' to remove duplicate breaks
breaks_z <- unique(as.vector(quantile(z, seq(0,1,by=1/max_breaks_cnt))))
breaks_z_rescaled <- unique(as.vector(quantile(z_rescaled, seq(0,1,by=1/max_breaks_cnt))))
# make a color palette
Pal <- colorRampPalette(c('yellow','orange','red'))(500)
# plot z_rescaled with breaks_z used as labels
ggplot(data.frame(x=c(1,2),y=c(1,2),z_rescaled),aes(x=x,y=y,color=z_rescaled)) +
  geom_point() + scale_colour_gradientn("z",colours=Pal,labels = breaks_z,breaks=breaks_z_rescaled)
```

This is quite off-topic but I like to use rescaling to send tons of changing variables to a function like this:

```
colorfunction <- gradient_n_pal(colours = colorRampPalette(c('yellow','orange','red'))(500),
                            values = c(0:1), space = "Lab")
colorfunction(z_rescaled)
```